# How to concatenate an int with a string in Python?

Tags: python

I wanted to concatenate the i of the for loop with xpath but it gives me this error "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str". How could I fix this problem?

```
    guardaremail = 'asd@asd'

    teste = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[text()='" + guardaremail + "']")
    tabela = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr")

    for i in range(1, len(tabela), 1):

        #verifica if tr = email
        emailteste = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/td[2]")
        botaoteste = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[" + i + "]/button[1]")

        #carrega no tr com id = "ui positive button"
        if emailteste == teste:
            botaoteste.click()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `"tr"+str(i)+"/td`

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
 emailteste = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/td[2]")

botaoteste = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(... "/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[" + str(i) + "]/button[1]")
```

Answer (score 1):

#### You may try using f-string instead of +

```py
emailteste = f"/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/td[2]"
botaoteste = f"/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[{i}]/button[1]"
```

Comment: If you use commas, `.find_element_by_xpath` might take `i` as a argument

Answer (score 1):

You can use pythons built in .Format() to concat str Like this, I changed " + i + " to {} with .format(str(i)) at the end of the str

```
emailteste = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/td[2]".format(str(i))
botaoteste = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[{}]/button[1]".format(str(i))
```